# Unresolved Symbol toInt() in MainActivity Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

this is my code for Main activity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

fun onButton(view: View?){
    if(view != null) {
        if (input1.text != null && input2.text != null) {
            output.text = (input1.toString().toInt() + input2.toString().toInt()).toString()
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am getting an error at the toInt() part stating it being an unresolved symbol, any help appreciated

Comment: try this `input1.text.toString().toInt() + input2.text.toString().toInt()`

Comment: try `input1.text.toString().toInt()`

Comment: are you resolved? if not, post your xml and I'll try and help you on this. I noticed there is no answer marked as correct, so assuming it is not fixed yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there were 2 problems

first being -> (unresolved symbol toInt())

I added these to app build gradle file & then cleaned project :

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' 
android{
...
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
  }
}
dependencies{
....
 kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4'
}
```

second being -> (this caused app crashes)

```
input1.text.toString().toInt() + input2.text.toString().toInt()
```

instead of

```
input1.toString().toInt() + input2.toString().toInt()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
input1.text.toString().toInt() + input2.text.toString().toInt()
```

instead of

```
input1.toString().toInt() + input2.toString().toInt()
```

**EDIT**

```
output.setText((input1.text.toString().toInt() + input2.text.toString().toInt()).toString())
```

Use **`editText.setText()`**

Don't use **`output.text`** because  `editText.text` expects an `Editable`, not a `String`.